Find the minimum and maximum values of a three-variable function

Find the maximum and minimum values of the function $u=x^2+2y^2-3z^2$ within the region $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 50$

During an ordinary extremum analysis, I identified the point $(0,0,0),$ which lies inside the sphere but is not an extremum. Then, I wrote the Lagrange function $L=x^2+2y^2-3z^2+\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-50)$ to explore the boundary of this region. However, when I try to solve the system: $$\begin{align}
L'_x=2x+2\lambda x=0 \\
L'_y=4y+2\lambda y=0 \\
L'_z=-6z+2 \lambda z = 0 \\
x^2+y^2+z^2 = 50
\end{align},$$ I get no solution and I'm unsure about what to do next. Am I even solving this task correctly?

@Vasili Those are perfectly valid solutions. Let for example $x=y=0$, then you can calculate $z$ from the last equation, and get $\lambda$.

@Andrei  Thanks, I didn't think of that

You are very close. The system allows three different solutions for $x=y=0$, for $x=z=0$, and for $y=z=0$. You can calculate the remaining variable from the equation of the sphere.
For example:
$$x=y=0\\z=\sqrt{50}\\\lambda=3\\u=-150$$
Can you check the other solutions?

The system does have a solution.
From the first equation we get $x=0$ or $\lambda=-1$. If $\lambda=-1$ we get $2y=0,-8z=0$, so $y=z=0$ and so $x=\pm\sqrt{50}$.
From the second equation either $y=0$ or $\lambda=-2$. If $\lambda=-2$ then $x=z=0$ and $y=\pm\sqrt{50}$.
If $x=y=0$ then in the third equation we cannot have $z=0$ (as $(0,0,0)$ is not on the desired sphere), so $\lambda=3$ and $z=\pm\sqrt{50}$.
You can check the maxima are attained when $x=z=0$ and the minima when $x=y=0$.

You can shortcut using Lagrange multipliers at all by noticing that if $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 50$, then $x^2 + 2 y^2 -3z^2 = 50 + y^2 - 4 z^2$. Since the constraint requires $y^2 \le 50$ and $z^2 \ge 0$, clearly this function has an upper bound of $100$ on the constraint surface. This bound is achieved for $x = z = 0, y = \pm\sqrt{50}$, so those must be the maxima.

There is another approach. The domain is a sphere, so the variables are “independent” of each other in a way.
The value of $x^2+2y^2-3z^2$ is minimal, when $x^2+2y^2=0$ and $|z|$ is maximal. So, $x=y=0$ and $z^2=50$. The minimum is $-3\cdot50=-150$ then.
The value is maximal, when $z=0$ and $x^2+2y^2$ is maximal. We have $x^2+y^2=50$, so $x^2+2y^2= 50+y^2$. It’s maximal, when $x=0$ and $y^2=50$. So the maximal value of $x^2+2y^2-3z^2$ is $2\cdot50=100$.
